# Recognizing and converting ternary operator to correct if statement

Tags: java, sudoku, ternary

I'm trying to figure out the below code and I'm having trouble with the ternary operator below.

```
            System.out.print(solution[i][j] == 0
                    ? " "
                    : Integer.toString(solution[i][j]));
```

Is this correct?

```
System.out.print(solution[i][j] == 0 ? " " : Integer.toString(solution[i][j]) );
```

The above statement can be represented by

```
            if (solution[i][j] == 0) {
                System.out.print(" ");

            } else {
                System.out.print(Integer.toString(solution[i][j]));
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your "is this correct?" is correct. It's just a removal of some white-space so it will be hard to mess it up. I think that your second statement is correct as well. Putting a ternary inside of a method parameter is a **BAD IDEA™**.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's correct. You just wrote a multiline statement as a single line, there's no difference at all - adding/removing white space has no effect whatsoever. And yes, the expanded version using `if/else` is equivalent. Why don't you test your code and see that it does, indeed, work correctly?